# tf.distribute.experimental.MultiWorkerMirroredStrategy() does not work properly

Tags: tensorflow, server, cluster-computing, distributed, worker

Enviornment settings for this project is

- ubuntu 18.04
- cuda 10.0
- cudnn 7.6.2
- created a virtual enviornment
- install tensorflow-gpu=2.0.0
- nccl 2.6.4

The code is

```
 os.environ['TF_CONFIG'] = json.dumps({
'cluster': {
    'worker': ["35.223.196.89:2222"]
},
'task': {'type': 'worker', 'index': 0}
  })
```

strategy = tf.distribute.experimental.MultiWorkerMirroredStrategy()

This does not work properly.
console details is attached below[image]

stopped after...
Unable to destroy server_ object, so releasing instead. Servers don't support clean shutdown.
why this error?

or how to work on MultiWorkerMirroredStrategy()?

Comment: Do you have multiple workers? Or do you mean to train across multiple GPUs on a single machine?

Comment: `MultiWorkerMirroredStrategy()` has [experimental support](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/distributed_training#types_of_strategies) for TF2.0>=. I would suggest you to either update your TF to the latest nightly or stable build. If the problem still persists then maybe raise an issue on GitHub.

Comment: I have multiple workers.it doesn't work.need to know how to work with multiple works in google cloud